# C 'Undefined Reference to'

Tags: c, undefined

I'm trying to add fat driver to cLK(bootloader for hd2) and getting error when compiling

```
aboot.o: In function `eval_sett_menu':
aboot.c:867: undefined reference to `fs_init'
aboot.c:870: undefined reference to `fs_load_file'
aboot.c:871: undefined reference to `fs_stop'
aboot.c:904: undefined reference to `fs_stop'
```

code from aboot.c

```
    fs_init();
    printf( "\n   fs_init() done!" );
    void *buf = NULL;
    fs_load_file("/LEOCLK.img", buf);
    fs_stop();
    ...
    fs_stop();
```

all fs_* in fs.h

fs.h:

```
#ifndef FS_H_
#define FS_H_

void fs_init(void);
long fs_read(const char *filename, void *buffer, unsigned long maxsize);
int fs_write(const char *filename, void *buffer, unsigned long maxsize);

#endif
```

help me please)

fs.h of course included

sorry for my bad englesh

Comment: This looks like a linker error message.  How are you invoking the linker?

Comment: Certainly the library/object containing `fs_init()` et al. is missed in the link command.